# How do I add a description to an InventoryAssembly using the Quickbooks Web Connector?

Tags: quickbooks

I am using the Quickbooks WebConnector to integrate with our Ruby on Rails based e-commerce site.  I am using the `ItemInventoryAssemblyAddRq` to create an `InventoryAssembly` object for each product in our e-commerce system.  I don't see a place for description field.  I wanted to put the SKU in the Item # field and the product name in the description field.   How to populate the description field of an item in Quickbooks?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the OSR XML reference:

```
<ItemInventoryAssemblyAdd> <!-- required -->
<Name >STRTYPE</Name> <!-- required -->
<BarCode> <!-- optional -->
<BarCodeValue >STRTYPE</BarCodeValue> <!-- optional -->
<AssignEvenIfUsed >BOOLTYPE</AssignEvenIfUsed> <!-- optional -->
<AllowOverride >BOOLTYPE</AllowOverride> <!-- optional -->
</BarCode>
<IsActive >BOOLTYPE</IsActive> <!-- optional -->
<ClassRef> <!-- optional -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</ClassRef>
<ParentRef> <!-- optional -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</ParentRef>
<ManufacturerPartNumber >STRTYPE</ManufacturerPartNumber> <!-- optional -->
<UnitOfMeasureSetRef> <!-- optional -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</UnitOfMeasureSetRef>
<SalesTaxCodeRef> <!-- optional -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</SalesTaxCodeRef>
<SalesDesc >STRTYPE</SalesDesc> <!-- optional -->
<SalesPrice >PRICETYPE</SalesPrice> <!-- optional -->
<IncomeAccountRef> <!-- optional -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</IncomeAccountRef>
<PurchaseDesc >STRTYPE</PurchaseDesc> <!-- optional -->
<PurchaseCost >PRICETYPE</PurchaseCost> <!-- optional -->
```

The fields you're looking for are:

```
<SalesDesc> 
 (this is the sales/customer-facing description of the item)
```

And

```
<PurchaseDesc>
 (this is the purchase order/vendor/manufacturer-facing description of the item)
```